# Using classes and enums in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Struggling a bit with the proper way to implement a class and an enum in C++.

```
class CrossingGateRoad {
    public:
        boolean PowerOn(byte relayNumber) {
            digitalWrite(relayNumber, RELAY_ON);
            return true;
        }
        boolean PowerOff(byte relayNumber) {
            digitalWrite(relayNumber, RELAY_OFF);
            return true;
        }
};
```

and then I'm trying to create an enum as follows:

```
enum {
    CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR, // no train in crossing area, also initialized state
    CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED, // train detected by the entry sensor
    CROSSINGZONE_EXITING  // train detected by the exit sensor, when sensor clears, state = CLEAR
};
```

In C# I would name my enum and specify the values:

```
public enum CommodityIndexSector
{
    Currency = 1,
    StockIndex = 2,
    GovernmentBond = 3,
    Metals = 4,
    Energy = 5,
    Grains = 6,
    Softs = 7,
    Meats = 8,
    Other = 9
}
```

and I would access it like so....  `enumname.enumvalue`.
I'm not 100% sure the class looks right either.

Comment: can be that you forgot the enum name? :)

Comment: enum class CommodityIndexSector { ... };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++ `enum` values appear at their outer scope. If you have

```
enum {
    CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR, // no train in crossing area, also initialized state
    CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED, // train detected by the entry sensor
    CROSSINGZONE_EXITING  // train detected by the exit sensor, when sensor clears, state = CLEAR
};
```

pretty much equivalent to have `#define` values.

To specify an enum type somewhere else you need to name it:

```
enum CrossingZones {
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR, // no train in crossing area, also initialized state
    CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED, // train detected by the entry sensor
    CROSSINGZONE_EXITING  // train detected by the exit sensor, when sensor clears, state = CLEAR
};
```

and you can reference the specific enum type:

```
CrossingZones crossingZones = CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR;
```

---

A more intuitive declaration regarding the values, is to have enum class as for the current standard:

```
enum class CrossingZones {
  // ^^^^^
    CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR, // no train in crossing area, also initialized state
    CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED, // train detected by the entry sensor
    CROSSINGZONE_EXITING  // train detected by the exit sensor, when sensor clears, state = CLEAR
};
```

and use these from scope:

```
CrossingZones crossingZones = CrossingZones::CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR;
                           // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: and use like so in a switch statement?   case CrossingZones::CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED.......

Comment: @dinotom Any particular problems doing so?

Answer (score 0):

In c++11 you can now use `enum class` and you may also specify the values for it. However you will need a cast to get the value back.

```
enum class Crossing_zone {
    clear = 0,
    occupied = 2,
    exiting = 1
};

int main()
{
    auto myenumvar = Crossing_zone::occupied;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to declare the enum:

```
typedef enum {
    CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR, // no train in crossing area, also initialized state
    CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED, // train detected by the entry sensor
    CROSSINGZONE_EXITING  // train detected by the exit sensor
} EnumName;
```

abd then access to its values through the following code:

```
EnumName::CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED
```

Comment: That's c-style. Not really recommended for c++.

Comment: Why is it not recommended? What are the problems using it?